# How do I know when it's daytime?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

For the "Day of the Dead" Challenge, I have to kill enemies during the day, but how do I know when that is?

Is there something in the sky that indicates when it's day vs. night? Or is it just on some sort of cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are indicators on some maps

The time cycle does exist on all locations synchronally but on some maps it's barely to not visible at all.

For example, **Concordia** has an active day-to-night sky changing while **Serenity's Waste** has not, although they lay adjacent to each other. Maybe this is linked to Concordia being fully atmosphered and Serenity's Waste's environment is majorly vacuum. Sometimes day and night can only be separated by a slightly different lightning tone, where on nighttimes everything gets a blueish "hue" making everything look a bit colder. Often this effect gets nullified on maps with many fiery elements like **Regolith Range**. On inside-building maps, we can't tell at any chance if it's day or night.

Comment: Do you know how long each time period lasts? And it doesn't seem to exist in Helios and Claptrap? A.k.a locations off Elpis?

Comment: I would avoid questioning the logic of Claptrap's consciousness tho. For the Helios situation i currently have no explanation at hand. Maybe it travels along Eplis to always stay in the shade of Pandora. But this is obviously not the case as Helios throws a shade onto Elpis sometimes in Borderlands 2. For the timecycle duration i'm searching the fandom this day or tomorrow.